# How to find double linebreaks in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, linebreaks

Take for example the following:

```
This text file has many


double linebreaks, What is the expression


too find  these?
```

Comment: Do you want to find double linebreaks only or *atleast* double?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use "regular expression" search mode:

```
(\r\n\s*$){2,}
```

Will find all instances of 2 or more blank lines, including ones that just have spaces on the line.

E.G. using a replace of `\r\n`

```
something



something else



another thing

Another








Another thing
```

Becomes

```
something

something else

another thing

Another

Another thing
```

Comment: I ran into this issue using FTP for an old server. This option didn't work for me. I also did not want to remove more than the doubled linebreaks. This worked well for me instead: `(\r\n|\r|\n){2}`. Replaced with `\r\n`, all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, select extended search mode and search for `\r\n\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

To find double or more linebreaks (and ignore single linebreaks), search in Extended Mode for the following expression:

```
\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

It will match this case:

```
line a


line b
```

but not this one:

```
line a

line b
```

If you want to search and replace, you need to modify the expression a little bit.